# Running python program with bash in windows says permission denied

Tags: python, windows, bash

Respected people 
I installed python 3.8 vscode and bash in windows 10 then I tried to run a program from bash but it didn't worked replied permission denied

But then I run it in windows cmd and it get executed
I am trying to solve this problem for weeks and didn't get anywhere 
I tried : checked pythonpath to the python 3 folder in enviornment variables; reinstall git, python; checked ownership of the folder its okay

But really I can't get anywhere
It will be a very big help from you if you take me out of this situation thankyou from heart
[image: this is the image of error in getting every single time]

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo python3 i_am_back.py`

Comment: One may wonder why are you running Python from under mingw and not a native Windows Python version.

Comment: Sorry bro my bad it didn't worked replied bash: sudo: command not found